# Concatenate list of strings

Tags: string-concatenation, ceylon

Say I have list of strings in Ceylon. (It does not have to be a `List<String>`; it could be an iterable, sequence, array, etc.) What is the best way to concatenate all these strings into one string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient solution is to use the static method [`String.sum()`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/String.type.html#sum), since that is optimized for a stream of `String`s (and uses a `StringBuilder`) under the covers.

```
value concat = String.sum(strings);
```

The other solutions proposed here, while correct, all use generic functions based on `Summable`, which in principle are slightly slower.

Comment: Hmm, why is this named `sum`? While I understand that it applies the `+` operation, it is nothing like a usual mathematical sum (e.g. not commutative).

Comment: `String`s are [`Summable`](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.1/module-doc/api/Summable.type.html). They form a monoid, but not a commutative group.

Answer (score 3):

Some other suggestions:

Since strings are `Summable`, you can use the `sum` function:

```
print(sum(strings));
```

Note that this requires a nonempty stream (`sum` can’t know which value to return for an empty stream); if your stream is possibly-empty, prepend the empty string, e. g. in a named arguments invocation:

```
print(sum { "", *strings });
```

You can also use the `concatenate` function, which concatenates streams of elements, to join the strings (streams of characters) into a single sequence of characters, and then turn that sequence into a proper `String` again.

```
print(String(concatenate(*strings)));
```

And you can also do the equivalent of `sum` more manually, using a `fold` operation:

```
print(strings.fold("")(uncurry(String.plus)));
```

[Try it!](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=8fac67b438e574b0aefa99885ba50752)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `"".join`, which actually takes `{Object*}`, so it works on any iterable of objects, not just `String`s.

```
value strings = {"Hello", " ", "world", "!"};
value string = "".join(strings); // "Hello world!"
```

The string on which the `join` method is called is the separator. An empty string `""` is simple concatenation.